# := operator not working with user defined variables inside mysql function

Tags: mysql

Executing the below line against MySql server 5.6.17 gives me the expected result :

```
SELECT @registered_countryCode := countrycode, @registered_gcmRegId := GCM_regid FROM slappdb.tb_register WHERE phonenumber = '123';

select @registered_countryCode, @registered_gcmRegId;
```

But if i include these lines inside a function, i get a syntax error at the first := operator :

```
DECLARE registered_countryCode SMALLINT;
DECLARE registered_gcmRegId VARCHAR(255);

SELECT registered_countryCode := countrycode, registered_gcmRegId := GCM_regid FROM slappdb.tb_register WHERE phonenumber = extracted_phoneNumber;
```

What am i doing wrong here? Using user defined variables with the := operator in a function seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 1**:

There is no such restriction on use of local or session/user variables in a function.

Use `INTO` to copy values into local variables.

**Change**:

```
SELECT registered_countryCode := countrycode, 
       registered_gcmRegId := GCM_regid 
  FROM slappdb.tb_register 
 WHERE phonenumber = extracted_phoneNumber;
```

**To**:

```
SELECT countrycode, GCM_regid 
  INTO registered_countryCode, registered_gcmRegId
  FROM slappdb.tb_register 
 WHERE phonenumber = extracted_phoneNumber;
```

**Example**:

```
drop function if exists today;

delimiter //

create function today() returns date
begin
  declare today date default null;

  select now() into @_now;

  select curdate() into today;

  return today;
end;
//

delimiter ;

select today();
+------------+
| today      |
+------------+
| 2014-05-19 |
+------------+
select @_now;
+---------------------+
| @_now               |
+---------------------+
| 2014-05-19 14:04:24 |
+---------------------+
```

---

There is a difference between `'='` and `':='` usage.

`'='` is for comparison
`':='` is for assigning.

Change your query as below:

```
SELECT @registered_countryCode := countrycode, 
       @registered_gcmRegId    := GCM_regid 
FROM slappdb.tb_register 
WHERE phonenumber = '123';

select @registered_countryCode, @registered_gcmRegId;
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct and i realized after some experimenting. Unfortunately I changed my question slightly just before you answered. Sorry about that. Any idea why i cannot use := in a function?